# How to add the custom rules in sonarqube for c# and trigger the same

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop, stylecop

How to add the custom rules created in stylecop or fxcop to sonarqube for c# and trigger the same.?
where i need to put the custom rule-set dll and xml file.??

Little help would be great..

Answer (score 3):

For FxCop it's pretty straightforward: in SonarQube, use the [*Template for custom FxCop rules*](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=fxcop%3ACustomRuleTemplate) (self-documented).

For StyleCop there was [a plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-stylecop) but it's now deprecated.

Comment: That's fine, Once i create the custom rule using this template.
It will refer to the **assemblies** and the **xml** files. I  kept those files according to the template descriptiption but still it doesnot work..
Am i missing something..??

Comment: Make sure to use [the latest C# Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin) with [the latest Scanner for MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) (requires Visual Studio 2015 to be installed). FxCop support is then native, you don't have to configure anything more.